# being removed vs gets removed?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-tense

Question I: Which one is grammatically correct?

```
1. Does order A remain effective after object B gets removed?
```

or

```
2. Does order A remain effective after object B is being removed?
```

Question II: What kind of tense is this? Present perfect?

Comment: Both are "correct"...what are you looking for?  // I would just use "_is_ removed".

Comment: @Cascabel Have you _read_ (2)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yup...what rule does it break? It's clunky, and  of course _has been_ or _is_  is preferable...

Comment: _After_ followed by a continuous usage. Covered before.

Comment: Lemme think on that...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, so (2) is incorrect because after should not be followed by a continuous usage: should I correct it this way: Does order A ... after object B has being removed?

Comment: ... after object B has been removed.

Comment: You leave a hospital after surgery, not when something **is being removed**. That's premature.